# Where to put SVG symbol definition in an HTML file for reuse?

Tags: html, svg, icons

I define an svg icon as a `<symbol>` and give it an ID , `icon-label`, that I refer to where I need it with `<use>`:

```
<svg class="svg-icon icon-label"><use xlink:href="#icon-label"></use></svg>
```

The SVG is as follows:

```
<svg>
<symbol id="icon-label" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<title>label</title>
<path d="M30.5 0h-12c-0.825 0-1.977 0.477-2.561 1.061l-14.879 14.879c-0.583 0.583-0.583 1.538 0 2.121l12.879 12.879c0.583 0.583 1.538 0.583 2.121 0l14.879-14.879c0.583-0.583 1.061-1.736 1.061-2.561v-12c0-0.825-0.675-1.5-1.5-1.5zM23 12c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"></path>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

and my question is where to put it. If I put it in the HTML body, I get a lot of vertical whitespace where the definition is. I'm using Django / Mezzanine, so I can put it in a `{% block extra_css %}` block in my derived template, and this works, but it doesn't really belong there.

Where should I define SVG symbols like this in my HTML tree?

Comment: Just use `display: none` on the second SVG, it doesn’t need to be displayed.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for that. In terms of the HTML file itself, is there a recommended place where the 2nd SVG element should be placed? E.g. at the very top of the <body> and thus kind of "out of the way"? Perhaps in <head> (are <symbols> defined in <head> even accessible to other parts of the doc? Seems like they should be)